# Can i put java files in a folder in a pydev project?

Tags: java, python, eclipse, pydev

I have a .java and .class file which i put under a folder inside my pydev project in Eclipse (because im primarily using python).

Inside my python script i wanted to call the java class file using os.system.

```
os.system('java -mx1500m D:\\projects\\socialsense\\src\\ss\\samplefile\\test')
```

However it says that my class file is not found. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you can do that.  However, most people would probably put the java source and python source in separate directory trees, and also not put `.class` and `.java` files in the same tree.  (If you lump everything into the same place you'll cause yourself pain when you try to implement a "clean" rule in your build file ... or when you want to check your project into version control.)

Your immediate problem is that you've got the command syntax for the `java` command wrong.  The name of the entry point class is specified by giving a fully qualified class name, not a pathname.  And you probably need to use the `-cp` option as well.

For details on how to do this right, refer to the [java manual page](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).